# Convert bytes to bits in dart, and vice versa

Tags: dart, binary, byte

I'm not expert in Dart, and above all not in bytes manipulation.
I use flutter_blue and and receive or send list of int like [211, 13, 67].
I read [enter link description here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/working-with-bytes-in-dart-6ece83455721) which is not intuitive for me but succeed to convert these kind of data into String or number,
but in some cases, I need to convert one byte as its equivalent 8-bits int, or vice versa.
For example : 0100000 -> 0x...., or [165] -> 01111111

Could you help me please ?
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want to convert your integers into strings which shows the binary representation of the integer? Because in Dart, there are no difference doing `int a = 0x10` or `int a = 16`.

Comment: @julemand101, yes. And from binary to integers

Comment: Ok, so you have a `String` with the content of some `0` and `1` characters you want to convert into `int`? Do you have some examples of these strings? Do they all begin with `0x`?

Comment: @julemand101, I have not String but list of int like [123, 45, 222...] read from bluetooth, and for the first, I wants its binary representation

Comment: But you just asked for "binary to integers". What do you even mean by that if the "binary" representation is not a `String`?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your answer well. As you said, it's from binary string to int, and vice versa

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234900/discussion-between-julemand101-and-turvy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does something like this do the job?

```
void main() {
  final list = [211, 13, 67];

  for (final number in list) {
    print('${intTo8bitString(number)} = $number');
  }
  // 11010011 = 211
  // 00001101 = 13
  // 01000011 = 67

  for (final number in list) {
    print('${intTo8bitString(number, prefix: true)} = $number');
  }
  // 0x11010011 = 211
  // 0x00001101 = 13
  // 0x01000011 = 67

  print(binaryStringToInt('0x11010011')); // 211
  print(binaryStringToInt('1101')); // 13
  print(binaryStringToInt('01000011')); // 67
}

String intTo8bitString(int number, {bool prefix = false}) => prefix
    ? '0x${number.toRadixString(2).padLeft(8, '0')}'
    : '${number.toRadixString(2).padLeft(8, '0')}';

final _pattern = RegExp(r'(?:0x)?(\d+)');

int binaryStringToInt(String binaryString) =>
    int.parse(_pattern.firstMatch(binaryString)!.group(1)!, radix: 2);
```